# Libraries to get depth map from stereo images?

Tags: computer-vision, stereo-3d, 3d-reconstruction, photogrammetry

I'm going to set up some devices to perform real-time 3D motion tracking. My first idea to do so is to use a pair of cameras to take stereo image and calculate the depth map to get the 3D data I needed.

Are there any good open source libraries (C/C++) available and is fast enough for real-time(~12-24fps)?
I've found [3D Reconstruction using Stereo Vision](http://sourceforge.net/projects/reconststereo/) and [EStereo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/estereo/) in SourceForge, have anyone tried them?

Or any algorithm suggestion that I can implement?

Answer (score 12):

Before you start, consider the fact that stereo vision is not just a software problem. The calibration of your pair of camera's is critically important to the accuracy of your depth map. For best results you want two identical camera's pointed exactly parallel, with exactly the same lenses on both cameras, with the CCD's of the camera's lying on one plane in 3D space. This is very difficult to achieve with just any random pair of camera's. Especially if they come from the cheaper segment.

If all you're interested in is using the 3D depth map for 3D motion tracking then there are precalibrated stereo camera's you can buy that typically come with software that allows you to extract the 3D map directly. I've had good experience with the [Bumblebee camera from Point Grey Research](http://www.ptgrey.com/products/stereo.asp) but probably there are other good systems as well. This will allow you to concentrate on the 3D tracking. Otherwise just getting a usable depth map from a camera pair will eat up a lot of your time.

Comment: I was originally planning to use a pair of PS3 eye as they should be less expensive. But the Bumblebee camera you recommenced certainly fits my needs. I'm requesting price quote, hope it is ok for me.

Comment: I've been contacting Point Grey Research but I still can't reach the local representative (Hong Kong)...

Can you suggest me a few more hardware choices?

Comment: any of these: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=stereo+vision+products ?

Comment: They contacted me and I think the Bumblebee is too expensive for me... I have looked into many others but all are too expensive relative to the PS3 Eye :(

Comment: Microsoft research vision group in Cambridge sell a dual camera for 300GBP - don't know if this is available in other ocuntries

Comment: @Martin Beckett Can you post more info on that? I can't find it in the group's homepage...

Comment: Perhaps using one camera with prisms and/or mirrors would be more feasible? There are quite a few resources various methods of doing this... if I end up going that route and it works I'll update here.

Comment: Also I found that the phrase "stereo correspondence problem" seems quite common in referring to the technical/physical challenges of ascertaining depth from stereo images, for those seeking further details. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Opencv has a whole section on this, see chapter 12 of [Learning Opencv](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134)

Comment: Thanks! I discover that too and have been working with it in the past few weeks! Here are the related functions' doc: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html